# Knockout.js - Set an attribute on drop-down without permanently binding to model

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js, custom-attributes, dropdownbox

I think I have a pretty generic question, but it is for a specific application.  I would simply like to know how it might be possible to set a custom attribute on a dropdown that equals the dropdown's initial value.  That value will be bound from a KnockOut view model value, but I don't want to have it be bound permanently, so that if it changes, that attribute's value does not change:

```
<select data-bind="options: availableSlots, attr: { preset: SlotPosition }, event: {'change', myChangeRoutine} " ></select>
```

In the example above, `preset` is my attribute, and I want to set it to `SlotPosition`, which is in my viewmodel and is what the dropdown will initially automatically be set to.  `availableSlots` is a MVC server-side-created SelectListItem that has slots 1 through x number of items that I return into my viewmodel as a ko.observableArray().  (It is in the server-side code that I set `Selected` to true where it needs to be set, for the given value, and build the options.)

The above example would bind my attribute `preset` to my model's value `SlotPosition`, but I just want it to remember that value until it is changed, instead of permanently binding to it.  The issue I have is that in `myChangeRoutine`, the value for `preset` has already become what the dropdown was changed to.  I want this to work so that when I change the dropdown's value and `myChangeRoutine` runs, I can do something with the old value.

Comment: I hope this is what you looking here is fiddle link jsfiddle.net/supercool/74dh736s/11

Comment: I think so.  I modified it to this -- http://jsfiddle.net/navyjax2/Ls5aw9xs  to match what I was trying to do in my code.  But for some reason, even though it works there using your baseline, it still sets the new value to `self.SlotPosition()` by the time `myChangeRoutine` runs in my actual code.  So I went the way that Max suggested -- see for my final code http://jsfiddle.net/navyjax2/7kkuwsLa/

Comment: `vapcguy` you can achieve this in a better way (cleaner way) . check the answer posted . `MaxBrodin` mention `peek()` is really useful but in your case there are better alternatives to cut down code .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make your `SlotPosition` as simple plain value, not `ko.observable`, this will be one time binding. 
Or use `attr { preset : SlotPosition.peek() }`, see [documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computed-dependency-tracking.html).

Comment: Unfortunately, can't make it a plain value, as I must save the position back to the database.  Were you suggesting adding a constant to the viewmodel that wasn't bound to the database?  Tried that - I still would have to initialize it as `self.SlotPosition` - and it still set it to the new value.  And I tried setting `.peek()` inline, as you suggested, but it still set preset to the new value instead of keeping the old.

Comment: Actually, I was initializing the constant I added to my view model, `self.Preset` to `self.SlotPosition`, when I should've been initializing it to `self.SlotPosition.peek()`, as you rightfully suggested.  This worked!  Many thanks!

Comment: So for anyone finding this in the future, to summarize what worked, I used `attr { preset : Preset }` on my `data-bind` on the dropdown, and `self.Preset = self.SlotPosition.peek()` in my viewmodel.

Answer (score 1):

Well this can be achieved in much simpler way no need for any change event and other stuff making view complex . just all we need is to use `subscribe`

**View Model:**

```
var ViewModel = function () {
    var self = this;

    self.availableSlots = ko.observableArray(slots);   
    self.Id = '999';
    self.SlotPosition = ko.observable();    
    self.Preset = ko.observable(1); 

     self.SlotPosition.subscribe(function(newVal){
         if(newVal == self.Preset()) return false;
         var newVal = self.SlotPosition(); 
         alert('newVal: ' + newVal);
         alert('oldVal: ' + self.Preset());
         // Then, I find my other dropdown from the next model 
         // using the newVal, and set it to oldVal
         // After doing you work set the newVal to self.Preset
         self.Preset(newVal); 
    });

};
ko.applyBindings( new ViewModel() );
```

**View :**

```
<div>
    <select data-bind="options: slots, optionsText: 'Text', optionsValue: 'Value', value: SlotPosition"> </select>
</div>
```

Without peek working fiddle using subscribe **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/supercool/7kkuwsLa/4/)**

With peek working fiddle using subscribe **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/supercool/7kkuwsLa/5/)**

Comment: Kudos! Looks like what you had was a `.subscribe()` when I had a change event & function. A matter of preference there, I think. Unfortunately, the idea was that the slot could be any number - not "1", so I could not preset "Preset" to "1", as you did in 'Without peek'. The value had to equal `.SlotPosition`, initially, so I had to either use `.peek()`, or because that ended up being buggy for me, I ran through all of the dropdowns on their initial load and filled `preset` manually with JavaScript from the dropdown value. Maybe there was a different way, but when you're working late...

Comment: I liked how you were able to use the model to set the values, vs. my getting/setting the attributes using JavaScript... just found I couldn't rely on that in my implementation since objects would not be saved until the end.

Comment: what all it takes is just a condition . check this (http://jsfiddle.net/supercool/7kkuwsLa/6/) without peek and no passing static numbers to observables . regarding comment 2 well ko works like that(view model will be in sync to view) . one thing here dont mix up ko with jquery(mostly but not always) . there are many options in ko which does your work . cheers